# How to remain in session after exiting tailf command from remote script

Tags: bash, powershell, putty, tail

Have PowerShell script from which I am executing the following command: `putty.exe -ssh user@srv -pw password -m Execute_Command_File -t`

During the script, `tailf /dir/log/` command is written into `Execute_Command_File`. After executing the script, requested session is opened and `tailf` is working.

The problem, when I trying to exit from `tailf`(ctrl+C), it closes the terminal.

Tried to add `/bin/bash` at the end of `Execute_Command_File`, not helping. And of course tried `tail -f/F`, also not working...

Any ideas?

Comment: Note! there is no a problem when using `tail` without `follow` option,
 or other command (`/bin/bash` is required in the end of the file). Assuming that `follow` option is causing it

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in persisting the SSH connection but leaving the nature of your `tailf` script the same, then try adding a while loop around it.

```
# previously
tail -f whatever

# with the loop
while true; do tail -f whatever; done
```

Comment: Still closes the session after CTRL+C